# create Html anchor to file on the c drive

Tags: html

H

could you tell me how to create a link to a file on the c drive(local machine)

or a link to download a file from the hard drive

this doesn t seems to work

```
<a href="C:/Documents and Settings/Giga/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaRssFeed/RssFeed/build/web/WEB-INF/Xml/Gaetano Feed.xml" class="font18">C:/Documents and Settings/Giga/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaRssFeed/RssFeed/build/web/WEB-INF/Xml/Gaetano Feed.xml</a>
```

The file is created by my application on the user machine, then all the files in the folder are displayed given the user the possibility to view in a browser

whith it doesn t work i mean it doesn t do anything
thanks

Comment: You'll have to give more information about what you're trying to do and how exactly this and AdmSteck's answer doesn't work. Is this href in an HTML page served by a web server? What do you see when they fail? Is the page served by a web server but the link is supposed to be to a file on the end-user's local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Giga/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaRssFeed/RssFeed/build/web/WEB-INF/Xml/Gaetano Feed.xml" class="font18">C:/Documents and Settings/Giga/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaRssFeed/RssFeed/build/web/WEB-INF/Xml/Gaetano Feed.xml</a>
```

Comment: Are you trying to show a file on the server, or on the machine that is being used to view the web page?

Answer (score 2):

The browser prevents linking to local files via hyperlinks.  The only way you can access the file is if you serve it via a web server.  Or type the *URL* on the address bar.